# How to Print zip file name which subfolders includes a specific string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, zip

I have many zip folders, each of them have many subfolders(subfolders includes zip folder or PDF or txt or xml). Some of them includes a file called "configuration.xml", some are not.

I want to search each zip folders and search keyword "1.2.0" in configuration.xml. print the zip folder's name if its subfolders includes "1.2.0" in configuration.xml.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Comment: Use the [zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Zip module and os.walk(path)